# microsoft msal graph ClientCertificateCredential path vs string, nodejs

Tags: reactjs, node.js, firebase, microsoft-graph-api

I am querying the ms graph api in nodejs using
`@azure/identity`, `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/authProviders/azureTokenCredentials/index.js`, and `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client` with a self-generated (and uploaded) pem cert and I am in an environment (google firebase) where I can't write to the filesystem, so I am storing the cert in a string that looks like this:

```
{
  [...]
  "tenant_id": "lalala tenant_id here",
  "client_id": "8db20[etc]",
  "pem_key": "Bag Attributes\n    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 \n  [....etc etc etc]98aets=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----',
  [...]
}
```

It was driving me nuts that I couldn't find any way to refer to the .pem as string instead of a file path; I tried mock_fs, putting the key in a bucket, putting the key in a file next to the relevant file.ts and calling it with "./key.pem", and various other things with no joy, then I noticed that there were alternate constructors for ClientCertificateCredential and I ended up using this form:

```
const credential = new ClientCertificateCredential(
    serviceAccountKey.tenant_id,
    serviceAccountKey.client_id,
    {
      certificate: serviceAccountKey.pem_key
    }
  );
```

And it totally works. I can go:

```
const authProvider = new MSauthProvider.TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider(
    credential,
    {
      scopes: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
    }
  );
  const graphClient = graph.Client.initWithMiddleware({
    authProvider: authProvider
  });
```

and query the graph successfully. But I keep getting errors I cannot trace in nested Promises all packaged up into a webpack-generated bundle. They look like this:

```
integrationsOnFetchswr0z9aqr6rl Error: The file at the specified path does not contain a PEM-encoded certificate.
at parseCertificate (/workspace/node_modules/@azure/identity/dist/index.js:3060:15)
    at MsalClientCertificate.init (/workspace/node_modules/@azure/identity/dist/index.js:3082:33)
    at MsalClientCertificate.getToken (/workspace/node_modules/@azure/identity/dist/index.js:1283:20)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@azure/identity/dist/index.js:3182:34
[... etc]
    at TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/authentication/azureTokenCredentials/TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider.js:61:67)
```

I roughly assume that inside of the promises, which use various queries to build, for example, a list of users, and an auditLog query of their signins, since the ClientCertificateCredential is created outside of them, they have forgotten the alternate constructor format? And are looking for a file at a path that looks like the text of the key contents? That is a guess. Any ideas?